# password_verify() is not working with simple code

Tags: php

Here is the code which i have used and similar code used for another login which works perfectly.

```
$password=$get_data[0]['password'];
$pass=$this->input->post('password');
if (password_verify($pass, $password)) {
$get_data_count=1;
$this->session->set_userdata('user_name',$get_data[0]['contact_name']);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_email',$get_data[0]['contact_email']);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$get_data[0]['id']);
} else {
$get_data_count=0;
}
```

It never enters in if loop.But for another login section i have used similar code and its work perfectly.And one more thing i have used option like $options = array('cost' => 11); for password hash 
Please help.

Comment: You have a double semicolon on line 2

Comment: You should check the content of `$pass` and `$password`. A simple way of doing it is the function [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), an even better method would be to use a debugger.

Comment: @rahulsingh edit your post to include more information, rather than putting it in the comments.

Comment: @martinstoeckli how var_dump will work to check that if given $pass is equivalent to $password

Comment: @rahulsingh - `var_dump()` won't check whether the values are valid, it just prints their content. I strongly suspect, that one of those variables have a wrong content when you call password_verify(). Check whether `$pass` really contains the correct password and `$password` really contains a 60 character hash. I would also recommend to use more descriptive variable names like `$enteredPassword` and `$passwordHash`.

Comment: Yeah @martinstoeckli is right, the only problem there can be your input or hash!